# Is $f$ necessarily a homotopy equivalence?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $X = \{(p, q): p \neq -q \} \subset S^n \times S^n$. Define a map $f: S^n \to X$ by $f(p) = (p, p)$. My question is as follows: is $f$ necessarily a homotopy equivalence?

Here is my progress so far. I don't really understand what Amitai wrote (specifically, the geodesic part). I know for the case of $n = 1$, the two spaces are definitely homotopic. For the torus, the subset $X$ is equivalent to the torus minus a loop $C$ which winds around the torus. We can just then unfurl the torus from that cut and get a cylinder with finite height, which can be then deformed into a circle. Something similar probably happens in higher dimensions, although I am not sure. I'm not even sure whether $f$ does the job or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is.

Define $g:X\to S^n,\quad (p,q)\mapsto p.$ Then $g\circ f=id_{S^n}$, and we need to show that $f\circ g$ is homotopic to $id_X$. We have $f\circ g(p,q)=(p,p).$ The idea is that since $q\neq-p$, you can move $q$ continuously along the geodesic connecting it to $p$.

**Remark:** The above $g:X\to S^n$ is a fibration with fiber $S^n\setminus\{\mathrm{point}\}.$ Considering the stereographic projection, one sees that $g$ is actually a vector bundle over $S^n$, and the above $f:S^n\to X$ is nothing more than the zero section.

Comment: Could  you elaborate on your "moving $q$ continuously along the geodesic connecting it to $p$" remark?

Comment: Once again, a downvote with no explanation... Dear downvoter, it would be helpful if you added a word or two on the reason for you downvote.

Comment: @user74301 It is actually customary in this site that when posting a question, one adds some context and one's attempts towards a solution. You didn't do so. Hence, I truly think what I wrote is enough, as it is, and that you should think about it further.